# From this table find a valid PK

Tags: database, relational-database, primary-key

[image]

Would this be a composite key as no row can be uniquely identified by just one PK?

So the answer would be

> (software,experiment)

Or i suppose the other way is by waying that the completion date can uniquely identify all the rows but is this allowed as a Pk?

Comment: Quote a definition of PK (more relevant is, CK) & show your work applying it & ask a question where you are first stuck. Right now you're asking us to rewrite your textbook. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the software + experiment could generate repeated values, perhaps the combination using the completionTime will make more sense, hope this helps!